# c# two levels inheritance hiding overriding methods

Tags: c#, overriding, shadowing

could you please tell me why the result of the code below is `BaseClass::method`?
I was thinking that DerivedClass2 will just override the virtual method of DerivedClass1 which is declared as new, meaning that the BaseClass method is not used. Or since the DerivedClass2 overrides a virtual method of DerivedClass1, then there's dynamic binding which will call the DerivedClass2 method version and not the one of DerivedClass1 or BaseClass. Any help? What's wrong with my reasoning? thanks

```
class BaseClass
    {
        public void method() { Console.WriteLine("BaseClass::method"); }
    }
    class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
    {
        public new virtual void method() { Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass1::method"); }
    }
    class DerivedClass2 : DerivedClass1
    {
        public override void method(){ Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass2::method"); }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            BaseClass e = new DerivedClass2();
            e.method();//BaseClass::method. But Why???

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a non-`virtual` method of `BaseClass`.

That is the method that will be called, regardless of whether derived classes add other methods.

Comment: but DerivedClass2 inherits the method from DerivedClass1. And DerivedClass1 has already defined it's own new method using the keyword "new", isn't it?

Comment: @Daveddd: Yes, but that isn't the method you're calling.  The whole point of `new` is that it _doesn't_ do runtime dynamic dispatch.

Comment: You're calling explicitly the base class method, if you cast to DerivedClass1 the result will be different or to DerivedClass2

Comment: what do you mean by "that isn't the method you're calling"?

Comment: @Daveddd: At compile time, you're calling `BaseClass.method`, which is not virtual.

Answer (score 0):

The `BaseClass.method()` is not virtual. It is **hidden** by a virtual method in `DerivedClass1`, which is then overriden in `DerivedClass2`.

The type of the variable `e` is `BaseClass`, and that's what the compiler uses to find the method to call. The only option is the non-virtual `BaseClass.method()`. If you change the type of the variable to `DerivedClass1`, the compiler will resolve the call to the `virtual new DerivedClass1.method()`. At run-time the `DerivedClass2.method()` will be called.

Don't expect polymorphic behavior when you hide methods with the `new` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Because in this line:

```
BaseClass e = new DerivedClass2();
```

`e` acts like `BaseClass` object. So it calls `BaseClass.method`.

It is like you wrote:

```
DerivedClass2 e = new DerivedClass2();
((BaseClass)e).method();
```

You have to read more and understand about Inheritance and Polymorphism.